# localhost doesn't work, after setup Virtualhosts

Tags: apache, localhost, webserver, virtualhost

I think I made a rookie mistake. But can't fix it.

I set up two VirtualHosts in httpd. Content, each index.html, is located at `/www/docs/Domain1` and ..`/Domain2`
The .conf files from the two domains are located in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/domain1.conf` and `/domain2.conf.`

httpd.conf is adapted accordingly.

I expanded `/etc/hosts` with:

`192.168.167.64 sales.test.pri sales
192.168.167.64 account.test.pri account`

http://sales.test.pri and http://account.test.pri in browser works. The correct content is displayed.

With http://localhost or http://192.168.167.64, I still get the content from one of the VirtualHosts. Usually the content of `/var/www/html/index.html` should appear.  That worked before setting up vHosts.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Apache will decide which VirtualHost to use with the IP, Port or domain name.  If it cannot match any VirtualHost, it will use the default one.  The default one is the first one it finds, as it reads the config file from top to bottom.  So add another VirtualHost on top that points to `/var/www/html/index.html`.  Or create a new VirtualHost for `localhost` of the IP address.  Note: we can't help much without seeing your configurations, hence my somewhat generic comment.

Comment: That was exact the info, what I needed. After creating new vHost for localhost, I get the right result. Thank you very much, Nic.

Comment: I transformed it as an answer, please accept :-)

Comment: accepted... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache will decide which VirtualHost to use with the IP, Port or domain name.

If it cannot match any VirtualHost, it will use the default one.

The default one is the first one it finds, as it reads the config file from top to bottom. So add another VirtualHost on top that points to `/var/www/html/index.html`. Or create a new VirtualHost for localhost of the IP address.